# Select text for right gravity, doesn't work in EditText control in HTC devices

Tags: android, android-edittext, htc-android

I'm developing an `Android` application in which I have an `EditText` control.
I've set the `gravity` to `right`, in order to type in *Persian*.
But when I try to select a text *(which is in Persian)*, the select pointers won't appear.
It works almost fine when the `gravity` is not set. Also it works fine in other devices like **Samsung**. But it doesn't work on **HTC** devices (*HTC One xl* in my case).

This is my `EditText` xml

```
 <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/txtShare" 
       android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:enabled="true"
       android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
       android:hint="@string/typeHere" 
       android:gravity="right"/>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1**

Also the cursor is always at the beginning of the lines, no matter where I tap in the text.

**Edit 2**

I'm almost sure that if I can solve the problem in *Edit 1*, the first problem will be solved along with it. Cause wherever I click in text, the cursor would remain in the beginning of the line

Comment: remove "android:editable="false"" from your code

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Did it. problem still there!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following attribute to your EditText

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using right-to-left text you should use the [textDirection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection) property for correct support. Gravity only aligns text, so text you enter would still be left-to-right.

Comment: I'm using API 8. and it says `textDirection` is available in API 17

Answer (score 0):

The cursor selection is handled in the onTouchEvent method.

I don't have any HTC device, so just an idea.

Maybe you can try to find the problem from the onTouchEvent method.